# Unable to find certification path even after adding certificate to cacerts

Tags: java, ssl

I have a simple java application which is running in my local machine which connects to some URLs. When I connect to https urls I get the Error "Unable to find certification path ..". Following the steps mentioned in other websites I exported the certificate from my browser saved it and then imported it into my cacerts keystore using the keytool command.

This worked initially for some remote website URLs. But when the URL began with "https:localhost:8083" I am still getting the same exception! Even though I followed all the steps.

Any help?

Comment: What are the sites where you cannot connect?  J2EE ships with certs for many sites.

Comment: Like I mentioned...some sites hosted on localhost...https:localhost:8083 etc.. I am not able to connect to these even after adding the certificate to java keystore

Comment: Have you imported the full chain? Ensure also you are using the updated JDK

Comment: actually I found the issue..well not fully but got it working at least..I was adding the cerificate to the wrong keytstore...there is a keystore within the path starting with jdk, as well as one starting with jre...Once I added it to the latter one it worked!